# How to add navigation menu inside #header in genesis child theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Genesis Child Theme, I need the navigation to position beside the title area.
How do I code the navigation to put it inside the #header after the #title-area so I can style it easily to look like the header on this child-theme: http://demo.studiopress.com/associate/

Comment: You may want to ask your question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Place a custom menu widget inside of the Header Right widget area. Choose the menu you want to display using the drop-down provided.

Answer (score 4):

hi this is the way I insert the navigation inside the `#header`

i put that code in my child theme `functions.php` after this `require_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );` and before this `?>` php end `tag`

code:

```
Remove_action('genesis_after_header','genesis_do_nav');

Add_action('genesis_site_title','genesis_do_nav');
```

**hope it help :)**

Comment: I tried the same, but it is not working. Still, the header and navigation are in separate containers.